# Is it possible to and worth getting certified in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for full time work as a web developer.  On the upside, I have 15 years of experience. On the downside, my skills have gone a bit stale because I spent the last five or so years spending more time doing marketing work, what little web coding I was doing was mostly maintaining content. My skills have gone a little stale as a result.

I'm working through the book learning AngularJS (*AngularJS Up and Running*) and I'm getting to grips with it. However since I don't have any experience of using it in a real application, I would like to get it onto my resume with some sort of credential.

Are there any certifications out there that would be worth getting?  Google throws up a few MOOCs like Udemy which apparently will give you a "certification of completion" once you finish their course, but I don't know how much value that has.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: I nominate GPRathour to be the person who writes *This question is off topic.*  under every question posted on SO.

Comment: I nominate 7stud to be the person who writes *I nominate GPRathour to be the person who writes This question is off topic. under every question posted on SO.* under every *This question appears to be off-topic* comment on SO.

Comment: "viewed: 26208 times" - off-topic?

Comment: Off-topic? I think this is very legitimate question to ask.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've never once heard of anyone being "certified in AngularJS", and I will admit the idea of it seems kind of silly to me personally.

AngularJS is a new, somewhat evolving open-source technology, so I'm not sure who other than the Angular team would be qualified to certify you in the first place.  And with 2.0 around the corner, things will change yet again.

I've hired angular developers, and the single best thing you could do (in my eyes) would be to build or contribute to a working open-source project of some kind and then know your stuff when we do a code review during the hiring process.

*Updated "somewhat unstable" to "somewhat evolving" ;)*

Comment: "somewhat unstable open-source technology", really ?

Comment: Well I assume you agree that it's open source and a technology, so presumably only have an issue with "unstable".  Write your app in 1.4, then upgrade to 2.0 in a few months and see if you need to change anything ;)

Comment: @tyler :unstable is too strong, 'evolving' is better ;)

Comment: @tyler I beleive that the only thing he has issue is the word "somewhat"

Comment: I believe the problem is that the definition of unstable is ambiguous in this case. Yes, it's very stable in the sense that it doesn't brake, but it's also unstable in the sense that it is still on an evolving phase.

Comment: Nice to know. A few days ago I had an job interview, and the interviewer asked me if I was AngularJS certified... which I responded 'I don't know if there's such a thing'

Comment: If any one know about actual Angular Js cretification then please share. It is or not ??